# Convolution Problem

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, convolution, signal-processing

while working on a signal processing problem i've reached to the following:

[image: convolution]

So my aproach was:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is it valid

Y(f)=[X(f) x H(f)]*W(f)=X(f) x [H(f)*W(f)]

If you could help me move further simplyfing Y(f)
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not valid, if it was, for every function $H$ you would have $H(f)\ast W(f) = H(f) \times ( 1 \ast W(f) )$

Comment: Τhank you ,just discovered it my self ploting the graphs.
So how do i proceed?
With integrals?
I made an effort but i got stuck at:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that

$H(f) \ast \delta(f-a) = H(f+a)$,

and that

$( H(f)+X(f) ) \ast W(f) = H(f)\ast W(f)+X(f)\ast W(f)$

So

$$\left\{ \left| \cos\left(\frac{\pi f}{50}\right)\right|\times\text{rect}\left( \frac{f}{50}\right)\right\} \ast \left\{ \delta(f-250) + \delta(f+250)\right\} (f)$$
$$ = \left\{ \left| \cos\left(\frac{\pi f}{50}\right)\right|\times\text{rect}\left( \frac{f}{50}\right)\right\} \ast \left\{ \delta(f-250)\right\}(f)$$
$$+\left\{ \left| \cos\left(\frac{\pi f}{50}\right)\right|\times\text{rect}\left( \frac{f}{50}\right)\right\} \ast \left\{ \delta(f+250)\right\}(f)$$

$$=\left| \cos\left(\frac{\pi (f+250)}{50}\right)\right|\times\text{rect}\left( \frac{f+250}{50}\right)+\left| \cos\left(\frac{\pi (f-250)}{50}\right)\right|\times\text{rect}\left( \frac{f-250}{50}\right)$$

Comment: So my mistake was not considering cos x rect as one function ?

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is it the same working with Integrals?

Comment: @Nick : Kind of, as $\delta$ is not a "real" function, but if you define as usual that $\int_{\Bbb R} f(x-t)\delta(t) dt = f(x)$, then it'll give you the same result